# JTable and JButton design difference

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I made a loading window to my application. 
After the runnig of the loading-window, I became the following button and table design:
[picture - changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUxs4.jpg)

The original design:
[picture - original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6X5A.jpg)

What is the difference between the 2 designs? I would like to have the original design...I just started my app from a new main class with the following code:

```
public class Start extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Loading ss=new Loading();
    ss.setVisible(true);
    try {

            Thread.sleep(1);
            AdminToolMain hh = new AdminToolMain();

            ss.dispose();
            hh.show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

}

many thanks!!

Comment: What's the difference in your code between the two?

Comment: @ifly6 I complemented the problem description with the answer...

Comment: That's more than a simple change you had to have changed the look and feel of the app and the table properties.

Comment: What’s the difference? Some is spewing with layout constraints without consideration to the difference between platforms and looks and feel - avoid call setPreferred/minimum/maximumSize and make use of compound borders and layout constraints instead

Comment: I surmise that the “original design” is been five within a form designer, which is probably using either the platform or custom look and feel, while you App is running with the “default” look and feel - what’s the answer? See my previous comment

Comment: @MadProgrammer The answer is the code in the post. That’s the difference between the two codes. I didn’t change anything else...

Comment: @Panama The two images are using different look and feels, which, to my experience suggests, someone is screwing with the size hits of the components inappropriately, but since all we have is done out of context code, it’s jus guess work